# sequelize query return Promise { _bitField: ...}

Tags: node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I want to **return** the value from `sequelize query` in another variable. I have to tried **different solution**, but i have the same result:

```
    Promise {
  _bitField: 2097152,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _boundTo: SellerPresent }
```

my js file(at the moment):

```
function findIdSeller(selectEvent) {
var match = {attribute: ['seller_id'], where: {event_id: selectEvent}, raw: true};
return models.SellerPresent.findAll(match)}

exports.findDataSeller = function (selectEvent) {
    var seller = [];
    return findIdSeller(selectEvent).then(function (result) {
        return  seller.push(result.seller_id)
    })
};
```

I need export this data in routes. How i can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be aware that asynchronous results cannot be treated (or exported) synchronously, so you need to stick with promises all the way.

Secondly, the `findAll` method will return an array, so you should not access the `seller_id` on that array, but on its elements. For that you can use `map`:

```
function findIdSeller(selectEvent) {
    var match = {
        attribute: ['seller_id'], 
        where: {
            event_id: selectEvent
        }, 
        raw: true
    };
    return models.SellerPresent.findAll(match);
}

// You can export a promise, not the promised value:
exports.findDataSellerPromise = function (selectEvent) {
    return findIdSeller(selectEvent).then(function (result) {
        return result.map(function(seller) {
            return seller.seller_id
        });
    });
});
```

You need to call `findDataSellerPromise` as returning a promise. So, for instance, if you need to use the promised data as a response in routing, then call `then` on it:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    // ....
    findDataSellerPromise(selectEvent).then(function(sellers) {
        res.send(sellers);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks tricot. My problem stems from the fact that I should handle multiple queries before sending the response. Can you help me?

Comment: Look into `Promise.all`

Comment: But this seems to be another question, as in your question there is only one promise, with its `then` method. Did I not answer that question?

Comment: Thanks. You just have rocked my world!